# Proper Table Design - How to create child table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-connection

I am not sure if this is the right forum - it is more about designing sql tables
I was trying to find answers online - no luck

I have menu permission table that list

- **permissionID** - sequential number
- **userID**
- **menuID** - id of the menu that user has access to

Once user gets to the menu - it may have some further restrictions, for instance there could be drop down with city names and user will have access only to some of them (or all).

To accomplish that I created another table called let's say menu permission child.
It has...

- **permissionID**
- **permissionChildID**
- **permissionOption**

Now...

- if user has permission to view all cities - I set permissionOption to -1
- if user has permission to some of the cities - I create separate entry in child table for each city

Query...

```
SELECT CityID, CityName
FROM Location
WHERE (CityID IN (
  SELECT permission_option 
  FROM PermissionMenuChild 
  WHERE userID = 1))
```

It works - but can someone come with more elegant way to do it?

Comment: FYI, this isn't a forum of any kind. It's a Q&A site. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Permissions (
    permissionID int identity(1,1),
    userID int,
    menuID int);
CREATE TABLE PermissionChildren (
    permissionChildID int identity(1,1),
    permissionID int,
    permissionOption int);
```

Let's say User 123 has permission to view all cities in Menu 234, then you'll have something like:

```
INSERT INTO Permissions (userID, menuID) VALUES (123, 234);
INSERT INTO PermissionChildren (permissionID, permissionOption) VALUES (@@identity, -1);
```

Let's say User 456 has permission only to vew a few cities in Menu 234, then you'll have something like:

```
INSERT INTO Permissions (userID, menuID) VALUES (456, 234);
DECLARE @permissionID int = @@identity;
INSERT INTO PermissionChildren (permissionID, permissionOption) VALUES (@permissionID, 11);
INSERT INTO PermissionChildren (permissionID, permissionOption) VALUES (@permissionID, 22);
INSERT INTO PermissionChildren (permissionID, permissionOption) VALUES (@permissionID, 44);
```

I am going to make some assumptions here:

- There are multiple menus.
- Some menus have child permissions, some of them don't.
- The majority of menus do not have child permissions.
- A menu can have multiple child permissions.
- When a new menu child is added, users with the all permission should have access, but other users should not have access.
- The query that you want to support is something like: Given a user, find all menus that the user has access to and all relevant child permissions.

I like your schema. You definitely need `Permissions`. This will support your menus that don't have children.
`PermissionChildren` is also necessary to support multiple child permissions. I don't think you need `permissionChildID`. 
SQL Server will create a unique ID for you anyway. But if it's your convention to have IDs on every table, that would not be horrible either.

I don't like the `-1` part of `permissionOption`. I think having no corresponding rows in `PermissionChildren` should mean that the user has all permissions to all children.
The reason is that when a menu does not have any child permissions, it shouldn't have any rows in `PermissionChildren`.
This configuration means that every user that has permission to that menu has permission to all children as well (all 0 of them).
When the first child is added to a menu, all existing users with permissions to that menu will have permission to it.

Overall, though, I like what you've done so far.